# C Function Pointer Not Compiling in Android Studio: Gives Error "Can't resolve type F"

Tags: java, android, c, android-studio, java-native-interface

I am trying to use a C program I made that compiles fine and works as expected (in Netbeans) in my Android Studio project.  I am trying to use JNI to incorporate my C program into my Android App (Java based).  My problem is I use pointer-functions and it gets lit up by Android Studio with a red underline.  Hovering over the issue reveals "Can't resolve type F."

Declaration:

```
typedef void (*PRF)(const void *keyPtr, UInt32 keyLen,const void *textPtr, UInt32 textLen,void *randomPtr);

void pbkdf2 (PRF prf, UInt32 hLen,
             const void *passwordPtr,
             UInt32 passwordLen,
             const void *saltPtr,
             UInt32 saltLen,
             UInt32 iterationCount,
             void *dkPtr,
             UInt32 dkLen,
             void *tempBuffer);
```

Implementation:

```
F (PRF prf, UInt32 hLen, const void *passwordPtr, UInt32 passwordLen, const void *saltPtr, UInt32 saltLen, UInt32 iterationCount,  UInt32 blockNumber, void *dataPtr, void *tempBuffer){
//do stuff
}
```

I literally copied-pasted my fully good C-code into my Android Studio project.

I tried cleaning and rebuilding my project, but the issue persists.

I re-tested my code in TexPad. It compiles fine, no errors. So, again, I copy it over to Android Studio. It gets lit up in red... It doesn't like exit(), free(), malloc(), and again the F. It seems to me perhaps the issue is the include stuff at the top of the C-file. Once I add "include `<stdlib.h>`" a bunch of the redness goes away, but some remains. Odd that TextPad compiles fine without it.

For clarity, the question should be **how do I get C pointer-functions to compile in Android Studio?**  That seems to be the issue since the code is valid syntactically and compiles fine elsewhere.  Obviously the issue is something with using C pointer-functions in Android Studio.

Thanks

Comment: What do you *think* `F` is in the tiny fragment of code you posted in which it appears (the second snippet) ?? The code you posted has only one usage for the identifier `F` : it both declares and defines a *function* named `F` which implicitly returns `int`, taking ten parameters, the first of which is a pointer to function taking five parameters. Either that is what you intended, it is wrong, and/or you didn't post enough code. I hedge it's probably a combination of those options.

Comment: Well, I wrote this thing over a year ago and haven't touched it since.  So I'm a little rusty.

Comment: You might consider starting with something a bit simpler and working toward that nightmare you've got going there.

Comment: Nothing I said prior has changed with your update. `F` remains what it was before: a function definition taking the specified arguments and implicitly returning `int`. Unless `F` is a macro expanding to something else, that's all it could be.

Comment: I'm not sure what to do here.  The code is over 1,000 lines.  I don't know how to proceed in fixing the error or what else I can offer up here that would help.

Comment: Surely you don't need 1000 lines of code to show a more complete example that might make some sense. Since your issue seems to be syntactic your example only needs to include that. Stub out functions, eliminate them altogether if they don't contribute to the issue. The onus is on you to provide the information necessary to have your question answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out!

For whatever reason Android Studio had an issue with a missing "void," whereas the other compilers didn't complain about it.

So, in Android Studio, this is the correct way:

```
void F( ...) {...}
```

That's it!